# A Tramp file is stuck in my buffer cache

Tags: tramp, ivy

I'm using Emacs 25.3.1 with Spacemacs 0.200.9. I have Ivy installed.

At some point in the past, I opened a Tramp session to a local machine over SSH.

Now, when I'm not on that network and I try to switch buffers (<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>), I get a spinner

> Waiting for prompts from remote shell...

and (after I <kbd>C-g</kbd> or it times out) I get booted back with my ivy-switch-buffer command aborted.

Tramp prompts me to `tramp-cleanup-this-connection`. I can see the connection listed in `tramp-cleanup-connection` but I can't figure out how to actually remove it from history. I assume Ivy or ido or someone is keeping additional history, but I haven't been able to find it.

How can I actually remove this Tramp connection from history? Moreover, what's a good way to figure out who's responsible for asking Tramp to connect here?

Comment: Ivy is independent of Ido, so unless you use the latter and see the same behaviour then, there is no reason to conflate it. Ivy does not keep TRAMP history, but it does inspect buffers when calling ivy-switch-buffer, so the issue could be arising when Ivy tries to inspect (e.g. get the buffer-name) of some stale TRAMP buffer. In other words, the issue is either TRAMP-specific or it lies with Ivy not handling TRAMP buffers in an ideal manner.

Comment: (Disclaimer: I am not familiar with TRAMP internals so take my previous comment as speculation.)

Comment: ivy history is in variable `ivy-history`. ido history is in variables `ido-file-history` and `ido-buffer-history`. Check them.

Comment: @MichaelAlbinus I don't think OP is referring completion history, rather artefacts of TRAMP connections, but I could be wrong so it would be better if they clarified.

Comment: Well, I guess my main question is how to even get a better handle on what's going on. I don't have a live TRAMP connection (because the target machine is unreachable and I've restarted Emacs). The prompt only seems to happen when changing buffers. So either TRAMP does something when I try to list buffers or Ivy calls TRAMP.

Comment: Call `M-x tramp-cleanup-all-buffers`. This will close all existing Tramp connections, and the related buffers.

Comment: If the prompt happens after restarting Emacs, does that mean something like recentf.el, desktop.el or similar is persisting Tramp state somehow?

Comment: I can see that `tramp-cleanup-all-buffers` deletes the connection, but the next time I try to switch buffers I trip over it again and I see that the connection gets added back in to Tramp.